# Magento: Use php in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am trying to use this request:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
```

In this piece of jquery code:

```
jQuery('#image1').attr('src',   /*Php code goes here*/  );
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: are you trying to mix client side and server side???? You lost me here.

Comment: Why don't you render the image with the correct `src` attribute initially? so no javascript is required.

Comment: Oke maybe i should give a bit more information.
Uhm..

I have an image which is resized on page load.
When i click on the image it opens a lightbox and in this lightbox it loads the image which was clicked on.

The image file is really realy big.
I resized it with the magento resize function to 235 by 350 to make the page load quickly.

Now when the lightbox opens it has a blurry image because i made a small image really big. (like half the screen).

So now i am trying to replace the resized image with a non resized image onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write it like this only

```
jQuery('#image1').attr('src', <?php  /*Php code goes here*/ ?> );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the PHP code outputs a string.

Replace your comment with:

```
<?php echo json_encode( $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ); ?>
```

`json_encode` should make it JavaScript safe (even if you give it something that can't be turned into real JSON, such as a string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your javascript in your template file, so that when the page is loaded, the javascript is given the correct data from Magento. The javascript will end up in the source of the page itself which is rendered along with the rest of the markup, resulting in you being able to pass server-side data to client-side functionality. Currently this is the only technique short of communicating with Magento via AJAX.

It looks like you're doing something with product images here so add the javascript to `/app/design/frontend/[theme]/[package]/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` and use Magento functions to get the images that you need, ie:

```
jQuery('#image1').attr('src', <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>);
```

*(This may or may not work with your template, impossible to tell until it's known where you're going to place your code, and what code is there. However it should get you on the right path!)*